# How click an icon to open a video?

Tags: media9

The effect I aim to produce can be witnessed by downloading and opening the PDF at the link below.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/8sl9ymcqlr5tfdq/AcroReaderMediaIcons.pdf?dl=0

As you can see if you download it, clicking the orange 'film' icon opens a window for showing a video clip. But you must download it and run it locally for this to work since the legacy media that it uses is now blocked in browsers for security reasons, and that's one of the problems I'm hoping LaTeX will solve for me. (The other problem is that my current workflow of rebuilding PDFs from MS Word requires laboriously re-entering all my numerous videos and their parameters individually.)

One strategy I'm experimenting with is to use the orange icon as poster text, by means of code like that just below. (Notice that it uses VideoPlayer.swf instead of VPlayer.swf since that makes the video play right away, at least with this code.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9} 
\begin{document}

\includemedia[
    label=firsttry,
%    width=0.4\linewidth,
%    height=0.3\linewidth,
    addresource=40631.mp4,
    windowed,
    noplaybutton,
    activate=onclick,
%    scale=2.5,
   flashvars={source=40631.mp4}
  ]{\includegraphics[width=32px,height=32px]{filmicon32x32.png}}{VideoPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

The MP4 file, orange film icon, and resulting PDF can be found here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/nyja912q7zh6xkd/AAD7fP-6F6Cg7TmCBNszWI4Ka?dl=0

The problem with the above code, and variants which reinstate the commented-out lines, is that the sizes of the poster and the video itself are linked. If I don't specify the width and height of the video, I get a tiny video to match the poster; if I do specify the width and height of the video, I get a huge poster to match the video.

A media command button strategy has led to other problems, but I will place attempts with that strategy in separate post so this one will keep its focus.

Comment: From @AlexG, https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/408492/30201

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The video size is `640x480` pixels which can be passed to the `windowed` option.

To make the video play right away in `VPlayer.swf`, add FlashVar `autoPlay=true`.

The code below plays the video at its original size in the top right corner of the Reader window:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{media9}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includemedia[
    %label=firsttry,
    addresource=40631.mp4,
    windowed=640x480@tr,
    noplaybutton,
    activate=onclick,
    flashvars={source=40631.mp4&autoPlay=true}
  ]{\includegraphics[width=32px,height=32px]{filmicon32x32.png}}{VPlayer.swf}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex. That solves the screen space problem at the same time. At least when I run it, though, autoPlay=true does not make it play immediately; one has to click in the window. This is not so bad since - contrary to my previous complaints - I now want the overlay controls to appear in the window after all for ease of re-viewing. This is because I stumbled on the technique of simply setting their opacity to a low value, making my subtitles visible after all. Unfortunately, when I edit the controls tab after the PDF is built to make them appear they do not; with the button they did.

Comment: @Peyton : The `autoPlay` issue has been solved in a recent update of the `media9` package. Run the TeXLive package manager to update the installed packages, either by running the graphical interface, or on the command line: `tlmgr update --all --self`. This should be done regularly, as LaTeX packages evolve quickly.

Comment: autoPlay is still not working, even after I tried to update media9 via tlmgr; maybe the reason is that the update failed (the 'date-modified' of media9.tex is 6/12/2015, which is about when I installed it; what happened is, when I tried to update it via tlmgr I got an error message saying "perl.exe has stopped working", and forcing me to close "the program". (= tlmgr or only perl? tlmgr does indeed close.) Doc on google says perl.exe isn't necessary, but there are 84 files with perl in their name in texlive/2014 (2015 was not yet available at install time; I'll try again now)

Comment: TeXLive-2014 isn't maintained anymore. You should uninstall 2014 and get the new one. As for overlay buttons, do you really need them?

Comment: I tried to install TeXLive 2015 yesterday. After 14 solid hours of waiting for it to finish, I got an error as it tried to install t1utils.win32. So now I'm going to pay more attention to what I believe are options I can choose to reduce the amount of what has to be installed. As to the overlay buttons, yes I do need buttons (overlay or otherwise) since my users will have a need to re-view each video clip to study it carefully, preferably frame-by-frame. It has to do with the eyebrow raises, head tilts, and so on that accompany signs in deaf sign language.

Comment: I installed only the basic scheme (plain and latex) but I can't seem to get media9 again. Media9.pdf says I should run the package manager, which I take to mean tlmgr, but media9 is not among its listed packages. kpsewhich TEXMFLOCAL yielded no output at all so I took a guess that the TDS might be texlive and extracted media9.zip to that folder. Then I ran texhash, which seemed to work. But the TeXworks editor still tells me it can't find media9.sty, which seems odd, since the file is indeed present in c:\texlive\media9...

Comment: After I ran "Load default" in tlmgr, media9 did appear on the list of its packages, but even after I updated it, the TeXworks editor told me it can't find media9.sty.

Comment: @Peyton This Perl.exe related error seems occur if running updates from within the TeXLive GUI. Can you try to run the update on the command line (in a DOS command window) :  `tlmgr update --self --all` ?

Comment: We're making progress.When I ran tlmgr update --self --all, it produced the following tlmgr.log: "[Sat Jul 11 09:33:26 2015] install: media9
[Tue Jul 14 20:56:40 2015] update: texlive-docindex (37815 -> 37842)
[Tue Jul 14 20:56:41 2015] update: texlive-scripts (37769 -> 37842)". And now pdfLaTeX no longer complains it can't find media9.sty. But after loading that, it complains that it can't find expl3.sty, which indeed does not exist on my C drive.

Comment: If I keep pressing Return it continues to complain it cannot find one file after another. Did I need to install more than the basic scheme, which I limited it to so as to avoid another massive 14 hour (and unsuccessful) install? What else do I need?

Comment: @Peyton I always install the full scheme, to be on the save side, minus some support/documentation packages for exotic languages.

Comment: @ AlexG  I think I installed the full package, though I can't be certain since I just let it run overnight, finding the next morning that something (the installation?) had rebooted my computer. The texlive directory was 6 GB in size, and there were 80-something little logs in the c:\texlive folder with date-times suggesting the whole process took just 39 minutes, unlike the 14 hours before. Anyway, I'm getting video again but I still have the two problems I had before: no autoPlay, and inability to invoke the desired overlay skin by updates in Acrobat - problems that VideoPlayer.swf lacks.

Comment: I gratefully accepted your answer above since it solved my major problems: saving screen space via a tiny icon as package, and escaping the drudgery of having to re-insert my videos whenever edits result in re-pagination. Based on my understanding of site rules and etiquette, I plan to pose my remain problems into a subsequent question.