# Embedded audio in to pdf

Tags: pdf, luatex, movie15, multimedia

I once had a very nice setup. I used `movie15` to embed `mp4` audio files in to a `pdf`. I used `tikz` to create a nice wrapper and used an play icon that could be clicked on and the audio item would item up in an external player. This worked in sumatra pdf and acrobat.

Now `movie15` is depreciated and just returns junk(errors or text like name `ABC@123` or something).

I have tried `media9` and can get audio to show up and play in acrobat but not sumatra(due to it using swf).

Is there any way to simply embed a file in a pdf and have a click on an object(image) open that file in an external player?

`movie15` worked well, but seeing that it is no longer supported, I don't know if it's worth trying to get to work. The errors I get(which are printed inside the pdf as normal text) are like:

```
name @MXV@EfAFaIEfJIAfIefjeIJIsjifJIASfJI xyz
width height depth /Subtype /FileAttachment/F 0/T (Myfile.mp4)/Contents (Media File (video/mp4))/AP «/N«»/R«»/D«»»/FS 202 0 Rwidth height depth /Subtype /Screen/Border [0 0 0]/BS «/S/S/W 0»/F 5/T (Myfile.mp4)/Contents (Media File (video/mp4))/P 21 0 R/A 199 0 R/AA 200 0 R/AP

\pdftexversion (fixed by doing \newcommand{\pdftexversion}{200})
\pdfdest 
\pdfannot
```

Any ideas? (Again, used to work fine before trying to update to latest packages, so it almost surely isn't some bug in the code)

Comment: For embedding the audio file as a file attachment and playback in an external app, use one of the dedicated pkgs, such as `embedfile`, `attachfile`, `attachfile2`.

Comment: @AlexG attachfile and attachfile2 seem to use their own icons rather than allowing one to define their own? Embedfile seems to put all the files at the end of the document? I also get stuff about missing files when I try to use them.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

In order to run a media file in an external application the `attachfile` or `attachfile2` packages could be used:

```
\textattachfile{myvideo.mp4}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{myi‌​con}}
```

where `myicon` is the basename of an image file (file extension removed) to be shown in the link area. Note that this solution requires proper application setting of the operating system for the media file type in question (during viewing time).

Answer (score 3):

The [`beamer`](http://ctan.math.utah.edu/ctan/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) bundle includes the `multimedia` package that allows sounds to be embedded directly into the PDF. The `multimedia` package works outside the `beamer` class

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\begin{document}
\sound[inlinesound]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{1024Tone.wav}
\end{document}
```

Note that the MWE requires a file called 1024Tone.wav