# Use filecontents environment to write a binary file

Tags: examples, filecontents, audio

In [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/345026/embedded-audio-in-to-pdf/408506#408506) of mine, I was trying to show how to embed an audio file into the pdf with the multimedia package. The resulting MWE does not stand on its own because it requires an example audio file.

I guess my first question is, does TeXLive include any example audio files? The second, and potentially less uninteresting question is, can I use the `filecontents` environment, or some other environment, to create a binary file?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}

% What goes in here to produce a usable wav file. Happy to use a different environment.
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.wav}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\sound[inlinesound]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{\jobname.wav}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can find sample audio and video files in `/usr/local/texlive/2017/texmf-dist/source/latex/media9/files/`

Comment: @samcarter thanks I gave up after not finding any wav, au, or aiff files. I guess I have to check and see if beamer can handle mp3/mp4 files.

Comment: The first idea that pops into my mind is: you could base64-encode your binary file, include the encoded version in a `filecontents` environment, and then expoit the shell-escape feature to decode the file at the receiving end.

Comment: is luatex a possibility?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle better without it, but happy to see a lua answer.

Answer (score 4):

If using luatex you can write binary files from Lua, here I took a chimes.wav from the windows directory fan it through base64 (cygwin utility but any base 64 encode would do)
to get the long string below. luatex includes the socket library which includes a base64 decoder so you simply need to write this out as a wav file for use later.

Not sure how useful this is for posting to this site as even this tiny sound file was 10 times the character limit of this site once base 64 encoded (you need some such encoding to embed in the main file, otherwise the bytes will be interpreted as UTF-8) so I have truncated the string in the code below (so it won't work as posted) (but it did work before I truncated it:-)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[implicit=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{multimedia}

\directlua{
io.output("\jobname.wav")
io.write((mime.unb64(
"UklGRiRNAwBXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAIARKwAABCxAgAEABAAZGF0YQBNAwAAAP////8AAAAA//8A
AAAAAAAAAP//AAAAAAAA//8AAAAAAAAAAP//AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAD//wAA///////////
PQISAfcBYAGeAaABOQHPAdAA6gFqAPIBDQDnAbj/xwFw/5IBNf9JAQr/9ADw/pYA5v42AO3+2v8A
stuff omitted!!!!
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA=="
)))
}
\begin{document}
\sound[inlinesound]{\includegraphics{example-image}}{\jobname.wav}
\end{document}
```