# Put the content of a binary file within filecontents environment

Tags: filecontents

I would like to include the content of a binary file within `filecontents`. Is there any way to do so?

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{file.txt}
    CPYA 4,3268 195 W64 #
    s   
     ÷˙÷˙‰    Y           Z*oG8#@      á~  a>  ‹-  ‚  î9  ˘o  É}                                          x   
        
    “   
      @˙ P   Ä        ÷ !Q        
             đ?      đ?        
    0                        Book1_A                  ÎM                              
    @  
\end{filecontents}
```

Comment: Tex can not write binary files done byteswill not be written by default and bytes that look like line endings Willbe normalised

Comment: Related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/408511/use-filecontents-environment-to-write-a-binary-file

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In this case, my goal would be to check whether the content of a file can be put within `filecontents` (without errors) or not. Is there any criterion to test this?

Comment: @TobiR you won't get errors just silent corruption. It depends on the settings of the user, eg it is a user commandline option or texmf.cnf setting whether to write control characters (bytes 0-31) as themselves or as `^^G` notation.  ends of lines are trickier as you can not tell from within tex what line embeding the file had originally so if there happened to have been a byte 13 or byte 10 in the binary stream you will see them as end of line with no way to distinguish them.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, Let me be more specific. I have a multi-file LaTeX project under Overleaf, which can be smoothly compiled and "run". I would download this directory and create `filecontents` from the auxiliary files used actively within the document to build the output PDF file. I have the list of ALL files within the project, but I would like to exclude the "non-text" files (like figures and other PDFs present in the directory) not needed to creat the output PDF. Do you have any idea how to do this to avoid creating incorrect `filecontents`? The .dep file (`snapshot`) does not help. :(